# Does LINQ to XML loads whole xml document during query?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a large `xml` file which contains database!
`400mb` is a size.
it was created using `LINQ` itself and it was done in `10 minutes`!  Great result!
But in order to read a particle information from that `xml` file using `LINQ` it need 20 minutes and more!
Just imagine to read a small amount of information needs more time then to write a large information! 
During read process it needs to call a function `XDocument.Load(@"C:\400mb.xml")` which is not `IDisposable`.
So when it will load whole xml document and when it gets my small information, Memory does not clears!
My target is to read "

```
     XDocument XD1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\400mb.xml");
     string s1 = XD1.Root.Attribute("AnyAttribute").Value;
```

As you can see, I need to get an Attribute of the Root Element.
This means that in `xml` file the data I need might be on a first line and query must be done very quickly!
But instead of this it load whole Document and then returns that information!
So the question is How to read that small amount of information from a large `xml` file using anything?
Will `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace be useful? Or create asynchronous operations?
Or is even any kind of technique which will work on that xml file like a `binary` file?
I don't know! Help me Please!

Comment: this is what streams are for

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000846/xdocument-performance?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

`Xdocument.Load` is not the best approach, reason being Xdocument.Load loads the whole file into memory. According to MSDN `memory usage will be proportional to the size of the file.` You can use `XMLReader` (Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx)) instead if you are just planning to search the XML doc. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx) documentation on MSDN.